# Will fillInStackTrace() is more cheaper when use in log4j?

Tags: java, exception, log4j

I'm using log4j in my application, just curious to know if I'm passing in an `Exception` object into logger, as in (1), will this consume more resource than if I pass in `e.fillInStackTrace()`, as in (2)? In other words, will (2) is more cheaper than (1)? Below is my sample code on log4j.

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(...);

try {
   ...
}
catch( Exception e ) {
   logger.error("blah blah blah", e);  // (1)

   logger.error("blah blah blah", e.fillInStackTrace());  // (2)
}
```

I am a bit confuse here, please help clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you look at `fillInStackTrace`, you will notice that the method is `synchronized`. Synchronization is considered a quite expensive operation in Java (or in any language) since it requires the aquiration and the release of a monitor.

Also, you should note that the `Throwable` returned from `fillInStackTrace` only records information about the stack frames of the call stack at the time `fillInStackTrace` is called. This information is collected directly from the JVM and then translated into an object representation which again costs resources. (Eventually, `fillInStackTrace` delegates to a `native` method which scans the calling thread's current call stack.)

However, you should mainly think about what you want to display in your log and decide by that criterion. When you explicitly call `fillInStackTrace`, the **current** call stack will appear in your log. That means that you will not longer see the *deeper* call stack that reaches into your `try` block (considering your example).

After all, you should always use variant *(1)* unless you explicitly need the information gained by *(2)*. I could not spontaneously think of an example in the scope of standard logging where solution *(2)* would make sense. You could however make use of *(2)* where you want to cut noise from your stack trace when you are writing some sort of framework and you want to clean away some top stack entries that are not related to the exception: For example, you might be using some sort of `ExceptionFactory` that creates the thrown exceptions for you. Then you do not want the stack trace to display the stack frames of these factory methods since they are not related to the error and would confuse the user who is trying to debug. Therefore, you would fill the stack trace manually by calling `fillInStackTrace` after receiving the exception from the factory.

Look at this example for an intuition of the difference of the two calls:

```
class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
       outerFunction();
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
       System.err.println("Outside:");
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  static void outerFunction() throws Throwable {
    try {
       innerFunction();
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
       System.err.println("Inside:");
       e.printStackTrace();
       throw e.fillInStackTrace();
    }
  }
  static void innerFunction() {
     throw new RuntimeException("A custom exception");
  }
}
```

would call these two different stack traces:

```
Inside:
java.lang.RuntimeException: A custom exception
at Example.innerFunction(Example.java:21)
at Example.outerFunction(Example.java:13)
at Example.main(Example.java:19)
Outside:
java.lang.RuntimeException: A custom exception
at Example.outerFunction(Example.java:13)
at Example.main(Example.java:19)
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two version is what the stack trace contains.

- In the first version, it will be the original stacktrace; i.e. for the method call in which the exception was originally instantiated.
- In the second version, it will be the stack trace for the current frame; i.e. for this method call.

---

> In other words, will (2) is more cheaper than (1)?

It is hard to say.  On the one hand, the call to `fillInStackTrace()` is redoing work that was previously done when the `Throwable` constructor called `fillInStackTrace()`.   On the other hand, the number of stack frames is going to be fewer (because you will have popped some stack frames).

However, this is moot.  The motivation for approach (2) is not (or at least, *should* not be) about performance.  It is about how much context you want to appear in the stack traces in the log file.